# Why is oxide an insulator?

Tags: mosfet

In a MOSFET, the oxide plays the role of an insulator. Is oxide synonymous with to SiO2 or O2?

What is the intrinsic reason why the oxide is an insulator?

Comment: Are you asking why SiO2 is an insulator? Why oxides in general are often insulators? From a materials perspective? Or why we want an insulator at all? Many of these would be off topic here.

Comment: @Matt : I know tha twe need an insulator. The question is why SiO2 is an insulator ? Why oxides in general are insulators ? What is an oxyde formula ? Is an oxyde formula a formula that contains O2 ?

Comment: O2 is not an oxide (unless you consider oxygen monoxide as one). Oxides in general are compounds of something with oxygen (eg. SiO2). Due to the tendency of oxygen to form strong tight ionic bonds with most metal atoms, most oxides are solid insulators.

Comment: @tobalt : thank you

Comment: Oxides are not always insulators. Indium tin oxide is conductive, and used in flat panel displays, for instance.

Comment: @Hearth - indeed, many metal oxides are, well, metallic. Coming from a semiconductor background this took quite some time to wrap my brain around.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian Could you change the Question title to specify which oxides you're interested in? I, for one, wouldn't have troubled to read on but for that odd unspecificity…

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin : my question was very general : I had no particular oxyde in mind.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian Exactly. Do you believe all oxides are insulators, or not?

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin : my culture on this thematic is low : else I would not ask questions. I don't know if all oxides are insulators.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian If you're trying to say English isn't easy for you, I'm sorry to hear that. Please look again at the Question and consider and consider editing it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "oxide" used in semiconductors is most often Silicon dioxide which is commonly known as glass.

It's an insulator because the molecule has filled valence orbitals which makes it stable. The molecule thus has no need to either give away electrons or accept electrons. So there is little electron mobility which would allow it to conduct. Therefore, it's an insulator and an excellent one at that.

Comment: sorry, you have an important explanation, but could you check grammar : I can't understand all details because of that. check what you mean by "on bound up in the molecule"

Comment: Silicon dioxide is not glass, as a category, and it does not have molecules. The silicon and oxygen atoms are covalently bonded. In terms of valence bond theory, the valence band is almost entirely full, the conduction band is almost entirely empty and the band gap is large, so silicon dioxide is an insulator: it does not have significant numbers of charge carriers than can move in response to an applied electric field.

Comment: That's funny, if silicon dioxide is not a molecule then what is it?

Comment: Further, if silicon dioxide is not glass then what is is?

Comment: It just is. Mostly found in nature as quartz, though. Also, most glass contains only about 75% SiO2.

Comment: glass is not a precise term. in application context it's a transparent solid of which there are many (e.g. diamond, al2o3 and gazillion others). In material science context, glass means mainly amorphous condensed matter. Again, any material can assume a glass structure given low enough temperature when being formed. And Alpha-SiO2 would not be considered a glass. And large anorganic compounds are almost never formed of individual molecules.

Comment: @jwh20 It's what's known as a covalent network solid. Other examples include diamond, boron nitride, and elemental silicon.

Comment: "if silicon dioxide is not a molecule then what is it?" – Well, it's a non-molecular compound. If you had molecules of SiO2, then each silicon atom would be bonded to only two oxygen atoms, and each oxygen atom would be bonded to only one silicon atom. In quartz, on the other hand, each silicon atom is bonded to four oxygen atoms and each oxygen atom is bonded to two silicon atoms. I don't know if the same is true of glass or not. (Quartz is silicon dioxide, and most glass is silicon dioxide, but quartz is not glass.)

Comment: Common glass is not silicon dioxide (or at least pure silicon dioxide) but a complex silicate. (Usually significant calcium, but other metals may be used as well. "Crystal" glass is largely lead silicate. Amorphous silicon dioxide in electronics is "a" glass, but isn't the same as common glass.

Comment: In other words, it's GLASS!  This is the electrical engineering topic area not chemistry.

Comment: No, it is not glass.

Comment: Note that the mineral quartz, which can be described by at least 2 crystal habits as a function of temperature and/or pressure. This alone precludes it from being categorized as a glass.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy: I think it would be simplest to say that *pure* SiO2 isn't glass, and that common forms of glass are mixtures whose primary ingredient is SiO2.  By way of analogy, "common glass" is to SiO2 as steel is to iron.

Answer (score 9):

Wiki page on [bandgap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_gap).

> It is the energy required to promote a valence electron bound to an
> atom to become a conduction electron

The bandgap of [SiO2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_dioxide) is 9.3eV [link](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/903/what-is-the-bandgap-value-of-sio2).

Compared to that, the bandgaps of other semiconductors are:

Si == 1.12eV

Ge == 0.7eV

GaAs == 1.5ev

That's why SiO2 can be considered an [insulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulator_(electricity)) for the range of voltages commonly encountered in semiconductors.

---

**EDIT-1 & II**

Mechanisms of dielectric breakdown have been discussed by Klootwijk et al, in a series of papers [I](https://ris.utwente.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/6692319/Verweij96dielectric1.pdf) and [II](https://ris.utwente.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/6511408/Verweij96dielectric2.pdf).

Comment: This is a very important point! While band gaps of amorphous materials are a little tricky, the gaps and the conduction bands that define them are still there, and one can potentially have conduct through them if the incident electron energy is high enough. e.g. [Diamond is a wide-bandgap semiconductor (Egap = 5.47 eV) with tremendous potential as an electronic device material in both active devices, such as high-frequency field-effect transistors (FETs) and high-power switches, and passive devices, such as Schottky diodes.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1369702107703498)

Comment: @tobalt My choice of language was poor. I have removed my comment.

Answer (score 3):

SiO2 is formed in the clean room during manufacturing.

SiO2 is an excellent insulator and is one of the keys of Silicon success.

SiO2 is an insulator because there are no free electrons in the outer orbitals of the crystal.

Comment: What are "outer orbitals of the crystal" ? There isn't even a crystal to begin with in SiO2 used as oxide in Si manufacturing..Its amorphous.

Comment: Ok it's amorphous but still there aren't free electrons that can move.

Comment: Agreed but then why call it outer orbitals of the crystal ? maybe you mean the other atomic orbitals that are close to the fermi energy?

Comment: By outer orbitals I mean the orbitals that are more distant from the nucleolus.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Do you have anything to back that up ? Usually SiO2 grown either natively or thermally (wet or dry) at up to many 100°C will be amorphous even when on single crystalline silicon. Also please look at Fig. 1.5. in this PDF that I just googled: http://www.iwailab.ep.titech.ac.jp/pdf/201103dthesiskawanago.pdf -> Clearly amorphous image taken from a "production" 90nm node product. If gate oxide was epitaxial, then people would surely also use epitaxial semiconductors on top :)